# Idiomatic way to turn an owned value into a reference with arbitrary lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime

Consider the following type

```rust
pub struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: &'a str,
}
```

If I try making a constructor for this type using a `String`, I'll run into errors about `bar` not living long enough:

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn new(bar: String) -> Foo<'a> {
        Foo {
            bar: &bar
        }
    }
}
```

Instead, the best I've been able to do is below. In my non-reduced case, I even have some `Box::leak::<'a>(Box::new(..))`'s floating around.

```rust
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn new(bar: String) -> Foo<'a> {
        Foo {
            bar: Box::leak(bar.into_boxed_str())
        }
    }
}
```

[This works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cfee84406d63ba7211010e2eee2ea7de), but I can't shake the feeling there has got to be a better way to consume my owned values into references with any arbitrary (non `'static`) lifetime. Are there any helpful utilities in the standard library or other rust tricks for this?

Comment: The idiomatic way is not to do that. If you want `Foo` to *borrow* from something, then you shouldn't try to make it *own* something. If you *do* want `Foo` to own the contents, perhaps you actually want `Box<str>`? If you want it to either own or borrow depending on the circumstances, perhaps you want `Cow<'_, str>`?

Answer (score 1):

**For the question**

Any var created in some scope has a lifetime restricted by that scope.

So you can't have an object that references a var that has a shorter lifetime (like what you try to do with new).

But, you can use smart pointers like `Box`es, owned vars, or you can leak a variable to use it as a static reference (what you do using `leak`).

---

**For the current code**

You construct `Foo` objects using Strings that are destructed/dropped after finishing `new()` function. And this is the cause of the compile-time error.

You must use a reference to a variable whose lifetime matches `Foo`'s lifetime. Like what follows

```
pub struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn new(bar: &'a String) -> Foo<'a> {
        Foo {
            bar: &bar
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=62f6b82515a3c6daa69b9f296e1d66a4)